# Is there any api to measure the time spent on an android app?

Tags: android

I want to calculate from time spent by the user on a particular application in andorid device .

Is there any api which targets towards that? Thanks

Comment: can you let me know if this helped? if so can you confirm the tick to say that your question has been answered?

Answer (score 1):

Flurry analytics SDK has that feature http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics